# pybind11: how to implement a with context manager

Tags: python, c++, with-statement, pybind11

I'm trying to implement a Python with context manager with pybind11.

Following [Python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers), my first version is:

```
    py::class_<MyResource> (module, "CustomResource", "A custom ressource")
    .def("__enter__", [&] (MyResource& r) { r.lock(); }
        , "Enter the runtime context related to this object")
    .def("__exit__", [&] (MyResource& r, void* exc_type, void* exc_value, void* traceback) { r.unlock(); }
        , "Exit the runtime context related to this object")
    ;
```

I don't know what the types of `exc_type`, `exc_value` and `traceback`. I guess they can be simple `pybind11::object`?

Are they more specific bindings, I can use?

Comment: Sorry for bumping an old post, but did you manage to implement a 'with' context manager using pybind11?  I'd like to do similar but am struggling with the binding syntax over at this question:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55452762/pybind11-destructor-not-invoked

Answer (score 4):

Indeed these arguments will come as Python objects, so you should use `pybind11::object` type for them. Using `void*` is not a solution.

Pybind11 is probably the best Python wrapper for C++ mechanism that uses C++ as its language at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Making everything a `pybind11::object` works fine, but if you want to be a bit more specific, you can make `exc_type` an `std::optional<pybind11::type>`, since `exc_type` will always be either `None` or a [Python type](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html?highlight=str#_CPPv44type), e.g.

```cpp
.def("__exit__",
     [&] (MyResource& r,
          const std::optional<pybind11::type> &exc_type,
          const std::optional<pybind11::object> &exc_value,
          const std::optional<pybind11::object> &traceback)
     { 
              r.unlock(); 
     },
     "Exit the runtime context related to this object")
```

However, since [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) was only added in C++17, you can only do this if you don't support C++11 or C++14.