# How to implement a Python3 with statement using pybind11

Tags: python, c++, with-statement, pybind11

Premises: I am not at all a C++ expert and I checked similar questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54025245/pybind11-how-to-implement-a-with-context-manager) and references therein but without much success...

I am developing Python bindings with pybind11 for a C++ project of which I am not the author.
Such a project implements a File Data Format.

One of the classes I managed to expose to Python is the one that implements the File object.
The class header looks something like this (among many other things),

```cpp
  /// Open a disk file in the specified mode
  XCDFFile(const char *fileName,
           const char *mode)
  {

    Init();
    Open(fileName, mode);
  }
  XCDFFile()
  {

    Init();
  }

  ~XCDFFile()
  {

    // Close-on-destruction behavior prevents assignment/copy construction
    Close();
  }
```

I managed to do (among other things)

```cpp
    py::class_<XCDFFile>(m, "File")
        .def(py::init<const char *, const char *>())
        [...]
        .def("__iter__", [](XCDFFile &self)
             { return &self; })
        .def("__enter__", [](XCDFFile &self)
             { return &self; })
```

But I don't know how `__exit__`should look like in this syntax.
Python docs say it should look like `object.__exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback)`, but I don't know how to translate this into pybind11, hoping that the class I am trying to expose doesn't need to be modified.

With the solution above I indeed receive the following error,

```py
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [2], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 with File("test_file_for_pybindings.xcd", "r") as input_file:
      2     pass

TypeError: __exit__(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (self: xcdf.xcdf.File) -> None

Invoked with: <xcdf.xcdf.File object at 0x10f430330>, None, None, None
```

Comment: Did you try to use `pybind11::object` for exception arguments like suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54025245/pybind11-how-to-implement-a-with-context-manager ?

Comment: Actually yes, that worked but I didn't realize it as there were syntax errors!
We should upvote that answer...

Comment: Now this works

In [3]: with File("test_file_for_pybindings.xcd", "r") as input_file:
   ...:     print(input_file.is_open)
   ...:
True

In [4]: input_file.is_open
Out[4]: False

but it's not doing exactly what I was expecting, because the files has been closed, but the input_file object is still existing in memory.

Any idea how to make sure it's deleted?

Comment: Hmm not sure if I understand the new problem, `input_file` is a pythonic object (wrapped from C++, but still) so it will be reclaimed by garbage collector in unspecified time. Maybe you can update the question with complete example and we'll see what's wrong.

Comment: It's actually a non-problem, more like a doubt :) I think you're right, the garbage collector is supposed to do its job when the number of references to the object goes to 0 https://stackoverflow.com/a/36002771/10401171